# Как преобразовать список в Python

Tags: python, список

Допустим, существует список:

```
s = ['аарона', '2', 'ааронов', '1', 'аб', '1', 'аба', '2', 'абажур', '1', 
   'абажуром', '7', 'абажуры', '1', 'абаи', '1']
```

необходимо преобразовать его таким образом, чтобы количество вхождений "слов" в список соответствовало следующей за словом "цифре", то есть, чтобы список приобрел вид:

```
s = ['аарона', 'аарона', 'ааронов',  'аб',  'аба', 'аба', 'абажур',        
     'абажуром', 'абажуром','абажуром', 'абажуром','абажуром','абажуром','абажуром',
     'абажуры',  'абаи', ]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать

Answer (score 1):

***Пример:***

```py
s = ['аарона', '2', 'ааронов', '1', 'аб', '1', 'аба', '2', 'абажур', '1', 'абажуром', '7', 'абажуры', '1', 'абаи', '1']

result = []
for i in range(0, len(s), 2):
    for k in range(int(s[i+1])):
        result.append(s[i])
print(result)
```

***stdout:***

```py
['аарона', 'аарона', 'ааронов', 'аб', 'аба', 'аба', 'абажур', 'абажуром', 'абажуром', 'абажуром', 'абажуром', 'абажуром', 'абажуром', 'абажуром', 'абажуры', 'абаи']
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, вы очень помогли

Answer (score 1):

Чуть другой вариант, мне кажется более питоновый по духу.

```
s = ['аарона', '2', 'ааронов', '1', 'аб', '1', 'аба', '2', 'абажур', '1', 'абажуром', '7', 'абажуры', '1', 'абаи', '1']

result = []
for w,n in zip(s[::2],s[1::2]):
    result.extend([w] * int(n))
print(result)
```

Результат:

```
['аарона', 'аарона', 'ааронов', 'аб', 'аба', 'аба', 'абажур', 'абажуром', 'абажуром', 'абажуром', 'абажуром', 'абажуром', 'абажуром', 'абажуром', 'абажуры', 'абаи']
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, вы очень помогли

Answer (score 0):

еще так можно:

```
s = ['аарона', '2', 'ааронов', '1', 'аб', '1', 'аба', '2', 'абажур', '1', 'абажуром', '7', 'абажуры', '1', 'абаи', '1']

res = []
[res.extend([x[0] for i in range(int(x[1]))]) for x in zip(s[::2], s[1::2])]
print(res)
```

Получим:

```
['аарона', 'аарона', 'ааронов', 'аб', 'аба', 'аба', 'абажур', 'абажуром', 'абажуром', 'абажуром', 'абажуром', 'абажуром', 'абажуром', 'абажуром', 'абажуры', 'абаи']
```

Comment: Не видел ваш вариант когда писал, так что оставлю пока свой тоже пожалуй, хоть и очень похоже вышло )

Comment: Огромное спасибо, вы очень помогли

Answer (score 0):

```
[elem for lst in [[word] * n for (word, n) in zip(s[::2], map(int, s[1::2]))] 
                                 for elem in lst]
```

---

Результат:

> ```
> ['аарона',
>  'аарона',
>  'ааронов',
>  'аб',
>  'аба',
>  'аба',
>  'абажур',
>  'абажуром',
>  'абажуром',
>  'абажуром',
>  'абажуром',
>  'абажуром',
>  'абажуром',
>  'абажуром',
>  'абажуры',
>  'абаи']
> ```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, и за редактирование вопроса

Comment: @ВиталийКочин, не стоит.